# t-SQL CAST date returns 2 days less

Tags: t-sql, datetime, date, casting

Can someone explain me why casting a datetime to date returns a 2 days prior date?

I just run into this, and need to understand.

Just execute this:

```
SELECT 
  CAST(FLOOR(CAST(GETDATE() AS float)) AS datetime) AS currDate, 
  CAST(CAST(FLOOR(CAST(GETDATE() AS float)) AS datetime) AS DATE) AS lessDays
```

In my Sql Server 2008 R2 Returns me this:

```
----------------------------------------------
|          currDate         |    lessDays    |
----------------------------------------------
|   2011-08-28 00:00:00.0   |   2011-08-26   |
----------------------------------------------
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I run it and get the same value for both columns...

Comment: What was the time in your local time when you ran this query? The two invocations of `GETDATE()` can return different results so if you ran it at exactly midnight that could explain a 1 day difference. If you consistently get different results can you try doing `SELECT <your_expression> FROM <some_table> ` and look at the execution plan and see what the compute scalar operations say?

Comment: Float is unreliable; the DATEADD/DATEDIFF is the fastest & most reliable

Comment: @OMG - You can just cast straight from `datetime` to `date` to extract the date. There is no need for any of this round tripping through `float` and `datetime`. Still doesn't explain the OP's observed results.

Comment: Ditto @Sparky. Same value for both columns.

Comment: @Martin Smith Agreed.  I'd get rid of the round trips first.

Answer (score 1):

This is a [bug in the JDBC driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7724258/date-columns-in-sql-server-mssql-jdbc-3-0-running-under-java-1-7-0-retrieved-a) not coping with the `Date` datatype.

[A hotfix is available](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jdbcteam/archive/2012/01/20/hotfix-available-for-date-issue-when-using-jre-1-7.aspx)