# SQL Server 2008 SYSDATETIME returns wrong date

Tags: sql-server-2008, datetime, jdbc

When I execute a select with `SYSDATETIME()` it gives me date two days in the past! Three of the date functions give me dates in the past and three give me the correct date. See below.

```
SELECT SYSDATETIME(),
       SYSDATETIMEOFFSET(),
       SYSUTCDATETIME(),
       CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
       GETDATE(),
       GETUTCDATE()  
==================================
2011-10-17 10:41:00.4521484
2011-10-17 10:41:00.4521484 -04:00
2011-10-17 14:41:00.4521484
2011-10-19 10:41:00.447
2011-10-19 10:41:00.447
2011-10-19 14:41:00.45
```

I am using MS SQLServer 2008 and the JDBC 3.0 driver:

```
DatabaseProductName: MICROSOFT SQL SERVER
DriverName: Microsoft SQL Server JDBC Driver 3.0
getDatabaseProductName: Microsoft SQL Server
getDatabaseProductVersion: 10.50.1600
getDriverVersion: 3.0.1301.101
getDriverMajorVersion: 3
getDriverMinorVersion: 0
getDriverName: Microsoft SQL Server JDBC Driver 3.0
```

Any ideas what is going on here?

Comment: SYSDATETIME should show you the date/time on the database server.  If your database server is on another server it may have the incorrect date/time.

Comment: @ArthurFrankel - But the inconsistent results are all coming from the same query.

Comment: hmm.  I guess that really doesn't make sense since SYSDATETIME and GETDATE should be getting the value from the server.  Possibly a driver issue?  When you run the query directly on the server (without the driver) does it work?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Date columns in SQL-Server (MSSQL-JDBC 3.0) running under Java 1.7.0 retrieved as 2 days in the past](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7724258/date-columns-in-sql-server-mssql-jdbc-3-0-running-under-java-1-7-0-retrieved-a)

Answer (score 3):

The Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server does not support JRE 1.7. I faced same issue while working with MSSQL server and JRE-1.7. Use hot fix(worked for me) released by Microsoft to resolve your issue.

**The hotfix is now available.** http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jdbcteam/archive/2012/01/20/hotfix-available-for-date-issue-when-using-jre-1-7.aspx

Please use compatibility information from above article and install appropriate fix according to your Application.

Hope This helps :)
Cheers

Answer (score 1):

First three functions in your query `SYSDATETIME(),SYSDATETIMEOFFSET(),SYSUTCDATETIME()` take the date and time of the computer **on which the instance of SQL Server is running**.

And the last three `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,GETDATE(),GETUTCDATE()` take date & time from the **operating system of the computer** on which the instance of SQL Server is running.

Comment: Is there any difference between these two statements? And where are you getting this from?

Answer (score 0):

We ran into this same problem and was able to fix it by falling back from Java 1.7 SDK to Java 1.6 (but not the _30 version, which has problems).

Answer (score 0):

Our solution to this problem was to switch to sqljdbc4-4.0.jar.