# Issue with a date extraction in SQL Server

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, spring

I'm trying to list the dates registered in a table with SQL Server, but my problem is all the dates I'm extracting differs of 2 days with the dates in the table.

For example, I got 2012-12-25 in my database and when I retrieve it and cast it to a Java.util.Date, it becames 2012-12-23...

I've got processes on dates in another table which are working fine.

I'm using SQL Server 2008, Hibernate 3 and Spring 3.

Edit:

The column data type for the table is date, I'm retrieving it using hibernate so here is my hibernate query call:

```
public List<Holiday> retrieveAllHolidays() {
    return (List<Holiday>) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Holiday")
    .list();
}
```

The holiday object got two attributes: a String and a Date (this one is incorrect after retrieving from database).

Comment: What is the column data type in the table? How are you retrieving the date? Can you show the code for the smallest possible program that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: try using a calendar object.. you'd need to update your mapping with `type='java.util.Calendar'` the issue usually is with java.util.Date Object.. i used to face such issues, then i switched to `Caneldar`

Comment: I've just tried the Calendar object and I got the same problem, the dates I extract are not in the same format but they're still wrong.

Comment: I would be inclined to say it's due to SQL Server having different types of dates where the timezone is coded into the date... but I can't explain why it would be two whole days.

Comment: And the fact is I'm using the date type in other tables and I've got no problem with these tables.

Comment: Let me get this straight, this happens only with THIS table specifically? So in other tables you don't have this problem!?
Do you always use the DAte type? Or is that DateTime?

Comment: Yep, only with this table. I always use the date type and I've checked my hibernates mappings for differents tables they are identic.

Comment: @Tony try putting the date values that do not work into the tables that work and vice verso. If values still work in other table than it's something specific to the table or table handling code. Check table creation SQL. Check java code. If values stop working then it's something specific to the way SQL Server handles those date values. Check if you have the latest patch. If you have old version the leap years might not be calculated properly.

Comment: [Could be this issue?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7724258/73226)

Comment: Thank you Martin !!! I've downloaded the hotfix and applied it... it works now :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was linked with the JRE 7 support of the JDBC Driver (a problem with the getDate() function).

See this post for more informations: [Microsoft JDBC driver team blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jdbcteam/archive/2012/01/20/hotfix-available-for-date-issue-when-using-jre-1-7.aspx)

Thanks again Martin smith for pointing to that other issue!