# Grails inserts and shows wrong date value when scaffolding

Tags: date, grails, scaffolding

I tried a lot to get correct date when scaffolding done with following example.
Database used is MS SQL Server 2008.

Details are given below. The issue is whenever inserts the date, SQL Server keeps wrong date. It displays also wrong date. 
For eg:- When I select date as 2/2/2015 it stores the value 1/31/2015 in database. It displays 2015-01-31 00:00:00 CT. This is being done scaffolding as well. Can anyone help?

Expense domain class

```
package moneytracker

class Expense {
    Date tranDate
    Float amount

    static belongsTo = [category:Category]

    static constraints = {
        amount Default:0.00
    }

    static mapping={
        id column: "intTranId", sqlType:"Integer",generator: "identity"
        amount column: 'fltAmt'
        tranDate column: 'dtDate',format:'yyyy-MM-DD'
        category column: 'intCatId'
        version false
    }
}
```

Table Structure

```
TABLE [dbo].[expense]
    [intTranId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL-Primary key
    [fltAmt] [float] NOT NULL,
    [dtDate] [date] NOT NULL,
    [intCatId] [numeric](19, 0) NOT NULL Foreign key to Category table
```

I tried different format and without format as well.Without any format in domain it gets insert correct value, but while displaying it displays wrong values like couple of days before...

Anyone can help me please?

Comment: Shouldn't the `format` for `tranDate` be `format: 'yyyy-MM-dd` with lower case `dd` instead of `DD`? ;)

Comment: I have tried with dd as well. Same result.

Answer (score 0):

This problem arises due to incompatible jdbc driver for SQL Server database. I've faced this problem too and found the solution from  [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9079639/issue-with-a-date-extraction-in-sql-server)