# Date is wrong in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, hql

I have written a HQL query, which creates a statistic report, with daily counts.

```
select cast(time as date), count(*) from table
group by cast(time as date)
```

The Eclipse Hibernate plugin reports a dynamic SQL preview, which is when run, works properly. The generated query looks like this:

```
select cast(time as date) as col_0_0_, count(*) as col_1_0_ 
from TABLE table0_ group by cast(time as date)
```

Everything is fine up until now, however when I run the HQL query, the date I get back is wrong (it is offset by exactly two days). This really *looks like* the same issue as [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9079639/issue-with-a-date-extraction-in-sql-server), however the hotfix does not solve it. I am using the latest Microsoft SQL Server driver, JDK 7 and Hibernate 4.3.8.

Have anyone encountered this issue?

---

These are my actual results:

**Received output**

```
     Date     |  Count
--------------+---------
  2015-03-01  |     1
  2015-03-02  |    43
  2015-03-03  |    29
```

**Expected output**

```
     Date     |  Count
--------------+---------
  2015-03-03  |     1   
  2015-03-04  |    43
  2015-03-05  |    29
```

I have also noted, that when I cast the date to a string, it works properly, so

```
cast(cast(time as date) as text)
```

yields correct results.