# Grails application showing wrong date

Tags: sql-server, date, grails

I've developed a grails application with grails-2.4.5, SQL Server 2008 R2 database and facing a strange problem. In one of my domain class there's a field of Date datatype. When i am submitting data from the respective form it saves it correctly to the database but in the show view the date shows two days ago the saved date. As for example I input 08 June 1992, it saves to database as "1992-06-08 00:00:00.0000000", but in the show view it becomes "06/06/1992"

I used the g:formatDate tag in the show page. ( `<g:formatDate format="dd/MM/yyyy"
                        date="${aaaOrganizationInstance?.dateOfEstablish}"/>`  )

Controllers save action:

```
@Transactional
def save(AaaOrganization aaaOrganizationInstance) {
    if (aaaOrganizationInstance == null) {
        notFound()
        return
    }

    if (aaaOrganizationInstance.hasErrors()) {
        respond aaaOrganizationInstance.errors, view:'create'
        return
    }

    aaaOrganizationInstance.save flush:true

    request.withFormat {
        form multipartForm {
            flash.message = message(code: 'default.created.message', args: [message(code: 'aaaOrganization.label', default: 'AaaOrganization'), aaaOrganizationInstance.id])
            redirect aaaOrganizationInstance
        }
        '*' { respond aaaOrganizationInstance, [status: CREATED] }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your input form's gsp code look like? And your controller too.

Comment: I think there's nothing to do with input form's gsp and the controller as i've tested the application with connecting the embedded in memory database of grails where the problem doesn't arises. Anyway, here's my input form view for date:  <g:datePicker name="dateOfEstablish" precision="day"  value="${aaaOrganizationInstance?.dateOfEstablish}" default="none" noSelection="['': '']" /> and the controllers' save action is added to main question.

Comment: Take a look at this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9079639/issue-with-a-date-extraction-in-sql-server

Comment: Thank you Emmanuel Rosa! Your provided link helps me to solve the problem. I've downloaded the updated jdbc driver for SQL Server and the problem is solved. Thank you again.

Comment: You're welcome. I'm going to go ahead and write this up as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a known issue with the SQL Server JDBC driver that causes your symptom. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9079639/issue-with-a-date-extraction-in-sql-server) a related question.

## The solution

To fix the issue you can install the updated JDBC driver [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jdbcteam/archive/2012/01/20/hotfix-available-for-date-issue-when-using-jre-1-7.aspx).