# Converting MS SQL Server 2008 datetime2 to Java

Tags: java, sql-server-2008

I have a date stored in my SQL Server 2008 database column MY_DATE as datetime2
My ResultSet is called rs.

How do I read the date in Java?

I tried

```
java.util.Date myDate=rs.getDate("MY_DATE");
```

I also tried

```
java.sql.Date mySqlDate=rs.getDate("MY_DATE");
java.util.Date myDate=new Date(mySqlDate.getTime());
```

However it understands the date 1 February 2012 as 30 January 2012

I could do it by converting to a YYYY-MM-DD String and then building the date using the day, month and year components, but I was wondering if there was a simpler way!

Comment: [There is a hotfix available for this.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jdbcteam/archive/2012/01/20/hotfix-available-for-date-issue-when-using-jre-1-7.aspx)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Date columns in SQL-Server (MSSQL-JDBC 3.0) running under Java 1.7.0 retrieved as 2 days in the past](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7724258/date-columns-in-sql-server-mssql-jdbc-3-0-running-under-java-1-7-0-retrieved-a)

Comment: Thank you Marin Smith. Just replacing the driver solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue related to the JDBC driver. If you update to JDBC4, you should be good to go.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=11774