# Java JDBC: dates consistently two days off

Tags: java, sql-server, date, jdbc

I am using Java JDBC to write a date to SQL server 2008 and then read it back.
The date that is read back is consistently two days earlier than the date that was actually written.

I am inserting the row containing the Date field with a prepared statement. The date value is provided by:

```
java.sql.Date todaysDate = new java.sql.Date(System.currentTimeMillis()) ;
System.out.println(todaysDate.toString()) // -> 2012-07-02
ps.setDate(8, todaysDate);
```

After writing the date to the DB, SQL server shows me the correct date if I run:

```
select date from table_name where date!=null // ->2012-07-02
```

If I run the same query via JDBC then retrieve the date value from the resultset using

```
java.sql.Date sqlDate = rs.getDate("date") ;
sqlDate.toString() // ->2012-06-30
```

The inserted row is the only row in the table with a non-null date so this does not appear to be a case of reading the wrong record.

I thought this would be a well known problem but the only reference I could find by a Google search for a "two days off" issue had no definitive answer.

Any ideas?

beeky (living in the past)

Comment: If you use preparedStatement, don't convert from or to String. Pass a date (or Timestamp) object to setDate.

Comment: What are the timezones of both the server and client?

Comment: Are you sure this isn't something to do with MM-DD-YYYY vs DD-MM-YYYY?  If your dates are going to and from strings, they can be re-interpreted by locale settings in interesting and unexpected ways (in the client runtime and in the database libraries and in database code).

Comment: @dystroy - I am using the java.sql.Date obj to set the value in the prepared stmt.  Did you mean to say the opposite, e.g. DO use strings?

Comment: @jim garrison  both will be in the same timezone, EST/EDT

Comment: @user903724 : no, I had just misread. Don't use string.

Comment: Could you put somewhere (sqlfiddle ?) your exact table structure and complete queries ?

Comment: It might be very interesting to print the time portion of the date values to see what the exact offset is.

Comment: Thanks for all the responses.  Unfortunately, nothing that was suggested had any effect on the problem.  I would like to restate the question as: If the date in the DB is correct what could happen to result in a day that is two days earlier when retrieved via JDBC.  I should also add that I'm using Spring jdbcTemplate to write and read from this table.

Comment: Related: StackOverflow.com, 2011-10-11, [*Date columns in SQL-Server (MSSQL-JDBC 3.0) running under Java 1.7.0 retrieved as 2 days in the past*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7724258/date-columns-in-sql-server-mssql-jdbc-3-0-running-under-java-1-7-0-retrieved-a)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

## Faulty JDBC Driver

It turns out the problem was the MS JDBC driver.  I tried every possible combination of date types and date conversions and nothing worked.  After a great deal of searching (should have done that first!) I saw a comment on [an older SO entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7724258/date-columns-in-sql-server-mssql-jdbc-3-0-running-under-java-1-7-0-retrieved-a) that implied the problem was the version 3 JDBC driver from Microsoft.  I got the latest driver, version 4.something, and the problem went away.

Thanks to all that tried to help.  Special thanks to you Mike for taking the time to post a  solution.

-=beeky

Comment: It's interesting, but I had same issue with Microsft JSBC 4 friver too, JTDS works correctly

Comment: Upgraded from jdbc 4.0 to 4.1 and this resolved the issue as mentioned.  JRE7 versions.

Comment: I've tried several versions of several different MSSQL jdbc drivers and all of them behave the same with SQL Server 2016 via JDBC, each of them returning a getDate or getTimestamp or ever getString from a date, datetime or datetime2(7) column 2 days shy of the value inserted.

Answer (score 5):

For those who are using maven, use this for java 8:

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>6.2.1.jre8</version>
 </dependency>
```

As it is pointed out, if you use an old version, you may face this problem, and it is not easy to debug.

Comment: As a minor point of fact (driver version number) enhancing a pre-existing Answer, seems like this should have been posted as a comment or as an edit to other Answer.

Answer (score 2):

I've run into this problem a couple of times recently and tore my hair out before remembering that if the field is of type date this happens, switching the field type to type datetime solves the problem.

Answer (score 2):

like what user903724 said, change to version 4 that would be fixed, but in my case, When I'm using sqljdbc4-3.0.jar, this issue still reproduces, but I change it to sqljdbc42.jar, this issue got fixed. Hope my experience would be helpful.
download from [sqljdbc42.jar](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=11774)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using MSSQL 2015, use this [Sqljdbc41](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/sqljdbc41/6.0.8112) to fix this issue

```
 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/sqljdbc41 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>sqljdbc41</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.8112</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

This issues is coming when we are using date DataType in Microsoft sql. I have fixed this to change date to datetime.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is Time Zone values ("GMT").
You need to introduce this manipulation in your `JDBC` fetching method as follows:

```
Calendar gmt = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
stmt.setDate(1, new Date(0)); // I assume this is always GMT
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
rs.next();

//This will output 0 as expected
System.out.println(rs.getDate(1, gmt).getTime());
```

Comment: How would TZ cause a two-day difference?  I can see one day near the International Date Line, but two?

Comment: Mike, was your example the answer to my question or a demonstration of how to see the timezone offset?

Comment: Mike,  Yes I tried it but, to be honest, I did not understand your example so I may have done it wrong.  new java.sql.Date(0) produced a date with year=1969.  After that, I did not pursue it any further.  If year=1969 tells you what  I did wrong please correct me.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem. The 2 day offset went away as soon as I used java 6 runtime environment instead of a java 7 runtime environment.

So it is possibly also a difference between the JDBC version 4.1 backwards compatibility with JDBC 3 drivers.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exact problem even using sqljdbc4 with Java 8.

Once i don´t need this field to make any type of comparison in the application i solved the issue by casting the field in my query like this: `CAST(dbo.tblPwActividadeParticipanteDetalhe.Data AS VARCHAR(10))`.