# Joda Time - Hibernate inserts yesterday's date into database

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jodatime

I'm having a weird problem right now. When I insert todays date into database, it's mapped into yesterdays date, it happens with every date. For example, when I try to insert 2016-09-02, database saves it as 2016-09-01.
Here is my mapping:

```
@DateTimeFormat(pattern="dd/MM/yyyy") 
@Column(name = "OrderDate", nullable = false)
@Type(type="org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalDate")
private final LocalDate orderDate;
```

I create instances by `new LocalDate()`
I tried printing the value on console right before it gets saved into database and it prints it correctly,  but the value in database is from the day before :/
So the problem is either with hibernate mapping, or with mysql.
I save the date into database in this method:

```
   @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
   public void persist(T entity) {
        getSession().persist(entity);
    }
```

I don't even know if it's a problem with hibernate, or mysql. This is really weird. Can you give me any pointers what could be wrong? Thanks in advance
The version of mysql im using: 5.7.14-log

Edit: when i manually insert data in mysql like this:

```
insert into Orders values (149,14,'2016-09-03','2016-09-03',199.99)
```

the date is saved correctly

My sql settings:
http://pastebin.com/87d6pkmE

I enabled logging in mysql, and code processed by mysql is:

```
2016-09-03T19:54:06.016215Z   125 Connect   root@localhost on ElectronicsStoreDB using TCP/IP
2016-09-03T19:54:06.017215Z   125 Query /* mysql-connector-java-6.0.3 ( Revision: 9fb85a76ccb7506157e668f1516464a46e317d4a ) */SELECT  @@session.auto_increment_increment AS auto_increment_increment, @@character_set_client AS character_set_client, @@character_set_connection AS character_set_connection, @@character_set_results AS character_set_results, @@character_set_server AS character_set_server, @@init_connect AS init_connect, @@interactive_timeout AS interactive_timeout, @@license AS license, @@lower_case_table_names AS lower_case_table_names, @@max_allowed_packet AS max_allowed_packet, @@net_buffer_length AS net_buffer_length, @@net_write_timeout AS net_write_timeout, @@query_cache_size AS query_cache_size, @@query_cache_type AS query_cache_type, @@sql_mode AS sql_mode, @@system_time_zone AS system_time_zone, @@time_zone AS time_zone, @@tx_isolation AS tx_isolation, @@wait_timeout AS wait_timeout
2016-09-03T19:54:06.018215Z   125 Query SET character_set_results = NULL
2016-09-03T19:54:06.018215Z   125 Query SET autocommit=1
2016-09-03T19:54:06.018215Z   125 Query SET autocommit=0
2016-09-03T19:54:06.021216Z   125 Query select product0_.ProductID as ProductI1_4_0_, product0_.Category as Category2_4_0_, product0_.Description as Descript3_4_0_, product0_.Discontinued as Disconti4_4_0_, product0_.Manufacturer as Manufact5_4_0_, product0_.Name as Name6_4_0_, product0_.UnitPrice as UnitPric7_4_0_, product0_.UnitsInStock as UnitsInS8_4_0_ from Products product0_ where product0_.ProductID=19
2016-09-03T19:54:06.045217Z   125 Query insert into Orders (CustomerID, OrderDate, ShippingDate, TotalPrice) values (14, '2016-09-02', '2016-09-02', 437.99)
2016-09-03T19:54:06.048217Z   125 Query insert into OrderDetails (OrderID, ProductID, Quantity, UnitPrice) values (163, 19, 1, 437.99)
2016-09-03T19:54:06.091220Z   125 Query update Products set Category='Printer', Description='USB 2.0, Wi-Fi', Discontinued=0, Manufacturer='EPSON', Name='XP-610', UnitPrice=437.99, UnitsInStock=134 where ProductID=19
2016-09-03T19:54:06.092220Z   125 Query commit
2016-09-03T19:54:06.094220Z   125 Query SET autocommit=1
2016-09-03T19:54:06.095220Z   125 Query select @@session.tx_read_only
2016-09-03T19:54:06.095220Z   125 Quit
```

so its the wrong date

found similar thread but it doesn't really help:
[dates consistently two days off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11296606/dates-consistently-two-days-off)
i'm using `jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver`

Comment: What's your timezone? If you're on the positive side of `UTC`, the date of `2016-09-02` will be `2016-09-01` in `UTC+0`.

Comment: Sounds like Kayaman is onto something. Would it be worth turning on / configuring the log output of Hibernate to see what SQL is being generated? https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-display-hibernate-sql-parameter-values-log4j/

Comment: I don't set timezone anywhere, my timezone is UTC+01:00
however, my jdbc url to database looks like this:
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ElectronicsStoreDB?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC

Comment: It's not the first this kind of question I've seen (but I can't find a suitable duplicate), but I'll bet you dollars to donuts that it's related to the timezone. I'm not familiar with the MySQL options you have set, so I can't tell you the problem off the top of my head though.

Comment: i updated post with my sql settings, hope it helps :(

Comment: @RobertBain , I configured the logger, the actual date sent by hibernate is
21:02:21,318 TRACE BasicBinder:65 - binding parameter [2] as [DATE] - [2016-09-03]
so i guess it's mysql fault :/

Comment: If your `serverTimezone‌​=UTC` but your app is `UTC+01:00`, do you need to your JDBC settings to be `UTC+01:00` too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alright, I managed to fix this
I changed jdbc url from:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ElectronicsStoreDB?useUnicode=tr‌​ue&useJDBCCompliantT‌​imezoneShift=true&us‌​eLegacyDatetimeCode=‌​false&serverTimezone‌​=UTC
```

to

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ElectronicsStoreDB?useTimezone=trueuseUnicode=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=Europe/Warsaw
```

And suprisingly it works as it should now