# Hibernate: Adding a date property to mysql database,it inserts into database as the previous day

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

So the date I am inserting(which is inside another object) is 2018/04/26,parsed from a String.Before I save it with debugging I can see it is correct,but when I request it from the database it shows as 2018/04/25.Any idea what is going on here?The database is an Amazon Web Services MySql RDS

This is my schedule class,inside it is a list of DateActiveScheduleItems which contains a date property.I am initializing the date like this

```
**Date date1=  new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd").parse(suppliedString)**
```

Schedule

```
@Entity
public class Schedule {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
private User user;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "usergroup_id")
private UserGroup userGroup;

private String description;


private boolean master;//is this a schedule for all supervalus(true) or one supervalu(false)

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "schedule",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<DateActiveScheduleItem> dateActiveScheduleItems = new ArrayList<>();

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "schedule",cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
private List<MusicScheduleItem> musicScheduleItems = new ArrayList<>();

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "schedule",cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
private List<AdvertisementScheduleItem> advertisementScheduleItems = new ArrayList<>();

@Basic
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private java.util.Date dateAdded;}
```

DateActiveScheduleItem

```
@Entity
public class DateActiveScheduleItem {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Basic
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date date;



@JsonIgnore
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "schedule_id")
private Schedule schedule;}
```

I am saving the object using the .save() method from hibernate CrudRepository.

Strangely enough the "date added" property in my schedule which I set to be "now" inserts correctly,which I initialize slightly different. Maybe I could try initialize my date for dateactiveitem this way but not sure how?

```
        Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
    schedule.setDateAdded(now.getTime());
```

Answer (score 2):

may be server timezone?
Check below thread - he had same problem.

[Joda Time - Hibernate inserts yesterday's date into database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39309920/joda-time-hibernate-inserts-yesterdays-date-into-database)

Comment: I tried altering my jdbc url like his but it didnt work unfortunately.I edited with more detail in OP