# Date type column is getting decremented on sqoop import by 2 days from SQL server to Hive

Tags: sql-server, date, import, hive, sqoop

I have one table in the database where `insertdate` is of 'Date' type. However, when I import the table into hive using sqoop values in hive tables are getting decremented.

Example

> RDBMS --> insertdate='2013-04-01'
>
> Hive --> insertdate='2013-03-30'

I have used below command to import data:

```
sqoop import --connect 'jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;username=XXXXX;password=XXXXXXX;database=XXXXXXXXXX'--table tbl_name \
 --warehouse-dir /user/hive/warehouse --m 1 \
 --hive-import --hive-database db_name --hive-overwrite --null-string '\\N' --null-non-string '\\N' --hive-drop-import-delims
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with Sqoop, it is with the **JDBC driver of SQL Server**.

Check related question - 
[dates consistently two days off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11296606/dates-consistently-two-days-off)

I think you are putting `sqljdbc4.jar` in `/sqoop/lib`.

Use `sqljdbc41.jar` or newer to fix this.

*(`sqljdbc41.jar` is compiled with Java 7)*

Answer (score 0):

Its working after adding sqljdbc41.jar.

Answer (score 0):

Solved in mysql by using parameter : **-D mapreduce.map.java.opts=" -Duser.timezone=GMT"**

sqoop import -D mapreduce.map.java.opts=" -Duser.timezone=GMT" \

--connect jdbc:mysql://hostname/location \

--username name -P \

--table VW_Location_History_For_Hadoop \

--target-dir /apps/hive/warehouse/test.db/location_h \

--hive-table test.location_hierarchy \

--fields-terminated-by "," \

--hive-import \

--delete-target-dir \

--m 1