# Problems with Date Java8 Hibernate5.2

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate

I used to use java.util.Calendar and java.util.Date, but now I´m facing a convert problem that I don't undestand. Every date that a work persists righ at the database but in the application miss 2 days.

My system uses
Java8
Hibernate 5.2
MS SQL 2008

Database
[image]

System.out
[image]

System
[image]

Actualy I'm using Calendar but it's the same problem with Date and LocalDate and LocaDateTime. There's any knwoing bug?

My Persistence

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="GEREVD" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>kmsimplecode.model.Log</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://server;databaseName=database"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="sa"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="pass"/>
            <property name="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans" value="true"/>         
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Answer (score 2):

Well there's nothing wrong in my code just the JDBC Edition to work with Java8

[Date columns in SQL-Server (MSSQL-JDBC 3.0) running under Java 1.7.0 retrieved as 2 days in the past](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7724258/date-columns-in-sql-server-mssql-jdbc-3-0-running-under-java-1-7-0-retrieved-a)

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=11774